# Command to close Server Window using RSelenium

Tags: r, rselenium

Using RSelenium I opened the server using the following code:

```
remote_driver <- rsDriver(browser= "chrome",
                         chromever = "114.0.5735.90",
                         verbose = F,
                         port = 8080L)
```

I can manually close the Chrome server window and use the client to do my website access without any problems. I tried to close the server window via the code, but I can't find the correct command:

`remote_driver$server` only gives me the function to "stop" `remote_driver$server$stop`, is there a way to just close the Chrome Window without stopping the server?